# Error reading file using JENA api

Tags: java, jena

For the following code:

```
Model m2=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
m2.read("Untitled.xml");
```

I get the error: `Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Untitled.xml`

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it expect an url, try `m2.read(new File("Untitled.xml").toURL().toString());`